# Sql sum two columns same id after result

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have this in a result:

```
+-------+--------+--------+-----+--------------+
| Count | Equipe | IdTeam | Id  |     Name     |
+-------+--------+--------+-----+--------------+
|    21 | A      |      1 | 358 | closs on D   |
|   107 | B      |      2 | 358 | closs D      |
|    15 | A      |      1 | 357 | Asos closs D |
|     9 | B      |      2 | 357 | Asos closs D |
+-------+--------+--------+-----+--------------+
```

I need this `total = count + count` if same Id

```
+-------+--------+---------+---------+-----+---------------+
| total |  Count |  Equipe |  IdTeam |  Id |      Name     |
+-------+--------+---------+---------+-----+---------------+
|   128 |     21 |  A      |       1 | 358 |  closs D      |
|   128 |    107 |  B      |       2 | 358 |  closs D      |
|    24 |     15 |  A      |       1 | 357 |  Asos closs D |
|    24 |      9 |  B      |       2 | 357 |  Asos closs D |
+-------+--------+---------+---------+-----+---------------+
```

so i add this :

```
sum(CASE WHEN t2_aop_appel.t2_aop_Zone_Id = t2_aop_appel.t2_aop_Zone_Id 
         THEN 1 
         ELSE 0 
    end) as total
```

so i try this :

```
    SELECT sum(CASE WHEN t2_aop_appel.t2_aop_Zone_Id=t2_aop_appel.t2_aop_Zone_Id THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) as total,count(*) as Count,t2_aop_equipe.Name as Equipe,t2_aop_equipe.Id as IdTeam,t2_aop_appel.t2_aop_Zone_Id as Id,t2_aop_zone.Name  
FROM t2_aop_appel   
join t2_aop_equipe on t2_aop_appel.t2_aop_Equipe_Id = t2_aop_equipe.Id
  join t2_aop_zone on t2_aop_appel.t2_aop_Zone_Id = t2_aop_zone.Id  
  WHERE  t2_aop_appel.t2_aop_Usine_Id = 1 AND t2_aop_appel.t2_aop_Departement_Id = 1 AND t2_aop_appel.t2_aop_Atelier_Id = 3 AND
  t2_aop_appel.t2_aop_Ligne_Id = 13 AND t2_aop_appel.t2_aop_Appel_Type_Id  in(1) AND t2_aop_appel.t2_aop_Equipe_Id  in(1,2) AND
  t2_aop_appel.t2_aop_Category_Id  in(1,2,3,4,5,6) AND t2_aop_appel.Appel >= '2017-11-20' AND t2_aop_appel.Appel <= '2017-11-26'  
 Group By  t2_aop_equipe.Name,t2_aop_zone.Id
```

result :

I have the same result in the column Count

some body can help me thx you

Comment: I don't think I can face trying to work with this naming policy :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a subquery

```
SELECT *, (SELECT SUM(Count) 
           FROM YourTable t2
           WHERE t2.Id  = t1.Id ) as Total
FROM YourTable t1
```

NOTE: In this case *YourTable* Is your query generating the first result. So you either repeat the query or save it as a temporal table.